# Implementing a document search engine in php

Tags: php, search

I have to implement a search engine similar to google drive search, that is suppose you have a folder with documents in it in different sub folders, I want to be able to search for the documents inside the folders (excel, pdf,...) and be able to search for specific text in the files also, similar to google drive. Is there any solutions for this yet? if there is an existing solution, I should be able to plug it into an existing php application.

Comment: AFAIK MySQL has full text search so you can create your own search. If you want good search engine then try Solr - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I would use a combination of RecursiveDirectoryIterator and file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be fast I would insert all the data of the files in your MySQL database, and perform your search on that database instead of on the files itself.

Searching in a database is quicker.